# DRF reverse cannot find view name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working of django rest framework api_root. It cannot find view even though I name it.

```py
# board/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from .views import BoardList, BoardDetail, api_root

app_name = 'board'
urlpatterns = [
    path('boards/', BoardList.as_view(), name='board-list'), # board-list
    path('boards/<int:pk>', BoardDetail.as_view(), name='board-detail'),
    path('', api_root),
]
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

```py
# board/views.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, permissions, serializers
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

from .models import Board
from .serializers import BoardSerializer
from .permissions import IsAuthorOrReadOnly

@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'boards': reverse('board-list', request=request, format=format) # board-list
    })

class BoardList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Board.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BoardSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

It throws error,

> Reverse for 'board-list' not found. 'board-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
> Why it cannot find view name?

Answer (score 1):

Since you included an `app_name` in your `urls.py`, you need to specify the view name with the app name, so:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'boards': reverse('board:board-list', request=request, format=format) # board-list
    })
```